# Singleton class pointer assignment doesn't work

Tags: c++, singleton

I have a class ABC which is singleton.(This is C++)
When I do

```
ABC *b = ABC::getInstance();
ABC* a;
a=b;
```

then when I check in debugger the value of b is not assigned to a.

In the debugger the value of a is shown as 0x00000000 and all garbage values for members of ABC (VS 2008 Debugger)

I did a *b in the debugger watch window and I see the valid values, when I do a *a I see all null and garbage values (This is after the above process is over)

Comment: What happens when you do `std::cout << static_cast<void *>(a) << " " << static_cast<void *>(b) << "\n"`?

Comment: I see nothing wrong here - what exactly does your debugger show? Have you tried just printing out the addresses?

Comment: The code is supposed to work fine as expected (if `getInstance()` doesn't throw any exception).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` and `b` are pointers.

The address they point to will be the same, although their specific address will be different.

One other reason might be that you're debugging in release mode, and you're not using the variable `a` afterwards. In this case, the compiler can decide to simply omit the declaration and assignment of `a`.

Comment: What is the "specific address" of a pointer? Do you mean their addresses, `&a` and `&b`?

Comment: Yes but I am not getting the same address for them...so what is the solution?

Comment: @seahorse *for* them, or *from* them? - there's the difference.

Comment: @thiton I mean `&a` and `&b`. It was just a guess... the code as posted should work just fine.

Comment: @seahorse if that is the case, post more code and tell us how you know they don't point to the same thing.

Comment: Try to call some function after that.
a = b;
a->Whatever();
Check if the function executes and if that solves the debugger problem. That will force your compiler to create the "a".

Comment: @RenanGreinert not necesarily... if it doesn't affect observed behavior, the optimizer can cut the function call out as well.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that debugger executed statement `a=b;`.

currently highlighted line in Debugger is not yet executed. so move the control to next line and check for values again.

This might sound stupid but this is the only reason i can think right now.

**Another reason, taken from Luchian Grigore's answer:**

> One other reason might be that you're debugging in release mode, and you're not using the variable a afterwards. In this case, the compiler can decide to simply omit the declaration and assignment of a.

Comment: try to assign a string after statement `a=b` and check is string is assigned properly. if yes, check value of `a` again.

Comment: +1 for asking where the user is testing the value. My immediate thought was "is the breakpoint on the `a=b` line, or after it?".